# SageMaker Predictor only outputs 0 and 1, i need the float between 0 and 1

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained a TensorFlow model on Amazon SageMaker with the following architecture:

```
_, timesteps, features = X_train.shape
ACTIVATION = 'relu'
EPOCHS = 50
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=np.nan, input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(LSTM(64, activation=ACTIVATION, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64, activation=ACTIVATION, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64, activation=ACTIVATION))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(64, activation=ACTIVATION))
model.add(Dense(64, activation=ACTIVATION))
model.add(Dense(64, activation=ACTIVATION))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(64, activation=ACTIVATION))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

adam_low = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001)

model.compile(optimizer=adam_low,
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

If I trained this in my local machine and do a prediction it will output float between 0 and 1.

But when I trained the same exact architecture with SageMaker with TensorFlow container, after deploying the saved model on an endpoint and calling `prediction = predictor.predict(x_predict)` the output is always either 0 or 1 only. Is there a way to force the prediction to output 0-1 float?

Answer (score 0):

The predictor doesn't do any processing of the output data other than deserialize it with the deserializer of your choosing. There are couple thing I would try to debug this

1, Download the trained model from S3 and do some local predictions to make sure the model is trained correctly.
2, Make some prediction requests to the sagemaker endpoint using boto3 or the aws cli directly without the SageMaker Python SDK.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the last dense layer's activation as "softmax"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).